# Replace XML field in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, replace

I am trying to replace certain fields of an xml file in python, the xml file looks like this:

```
      ...
      <DialogEntry ID="179" IsRoot="false" IsGroup="false" NodeColor="Pink" DelaySimStatus="false" FalseCondtionAction="Block" ConditionPriority="Normal">
        <Fields>
          <Field Hint="(Wird Ingame nicht verwendet.)" Type="Text">
            <Title>Title</Title>
            <Value>Reaktion TS34 Antwort 2</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Hint="The actor who is talking." Type="Actor">
            <Title>Actor</Title>
            <Value>2</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Hint="The actor who is listening." Type="Actor">
            <Title>Conversant</Title>
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Hint="The text that is spoken by the actor." Type="Localization">
            <Title>Dialogue Text</Title>
            <Value>[Speaking]</Value>




          <Field Hint="Audiofile to play" Type="Text">
            <Title>Audio-File</Title>
            <Value />
          </Field>




        </Fields>
        <ReviewerNotes />
        <ReviewerStatus>None</ReviewerStatus>
        <OutgoingLinks />
        <ConditionsString />
        <UserScript />
      </DialogEntry>
    </DialogEntries>
```

Please note that the xml **file consists of multiple DialogEntries** and there are more Fields than the ones shown but what I want to do is: For a certain DialogEntry ID for example 179 **I want to replace:** `<Title>Audio-File</Title>...<Value />` with generic text like `<Title>Audio-File</Title>...<Value>Audiofile_XYZ.mp3</Value>`

I have been trying with regular expressions, somethingl like this:

```
  r1 = re.compile("<DialogEntry ID=\"%d\".*?<Title>Audio-File</Title>\n {16}<Value />" % (id_to change),re.DOTALL)
  r2 = re.compile("<DialogEntry ID=\"%d\".*?<Title>Audio-File</Title>\n {16}<Value>%s</Value>"  % (id_to change, filename), re.DOTALL)
  content = re.sub(r1,r2 ,content)
```

but I am stuck because it's not working as expected.
The problems I have are:

- Making the RE match multiple lines(re.DOTALL seams only to work with precompiled REs for re.sub())
- The indicator ID and the part to replace are quite far away and there is a lot of dynamic text inbetween, how can I identify the correct DialogueEntry and still replace only the part I want to change without having to deal with the Titles between Audio-File and ID

Can you please help me out or show me a more appropritate way to do these changes?

Regards,
BPR

Comment: I'm not a fan of cliche, but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: Or, even better, here's a good explanation of *why* you don't *want* to use regex to parse XML (even though it's kinda-sorta-possible): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider a more appropriate medium for your transformations: XML -> text -> XML is doomed to failure / unnecessary complexity for non-trivial problems.

Perhaps it'd be best to parse the file using the [ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (consider using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) if performance is important). Then you can [modify the XML representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) for your `<Value/>` nodes in the tree using the API, and then [write to an output file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

Alternatively, outside of Python completely (or *almost* completely, depending how you invoke it), you could even just use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform this XML to slightly different XML; that's what it was designed for after all.